# How to understand completed path algebra?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory

Let $Q$ be a finite quiver (finite vertices and finite arrows).

Let $\widehat{\mathbb{C}Q}$ be the completed path algebra, i.e., the completion of the path algebra at the ideal generated by the arrows of $Q$.

I am confused how to to understand completed path algebra.

Added: Some literatures told that $\widehat{\mathbb{C}Q}$ is a topological algebra and the paths of $Q$ form a topologial basis so that the underlying vector space of $\widehat{\mathbb{C}Q}$ is $$\prod_{p \ \text{ path}}kp.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completion is the $I$-adic completion, which endows the algebra with the [$I$-adic topology (or Krull topology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(algebra)#Krull_topology).

More precisely, in this case, take $I$ to be the ideal generated by all the arrows of $Q$.  Then we have a sequence of surjections
$$
\ldots \to \mathbb{C}Q/I^3 \to \mathbb{C}Q/I^2 \to \mathbb{C}Q/I
$$
and the completion is defined as the limit of this inverse system of morphisms; in other words,
$$
\widehat{\mathbb{C}Q} := \lim (\mathbb{C}Q/I^n).
$$

So, indeed, as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, the completion is the direct product $\prod_{p \ {\rm path}} \mathbb{C}p$.

The $I$-adic topology is then defined as the smallest ring topology for which the powers of $I$ form a basis of neighbourhoods of $0$.