# The underlying vector space of the completed path algebra

Tags: representation-theory, quiver, formal-completions

I'm looking at the following question, whose answer I disagree with:
[How to understand completed path algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059398/how-to-understand-completed-path-algebra)

For context, let $Q = (V, A)$ be a quiver with infinitely many arrows. Then it is often useful to consider the **completed path algebra** $\widehat{kQ}$: this is the $I$-adic completion of $kQ$, where $I$ is the ideal generated generated by the set of arrows $A$. In other words, $\widehat{kQ}$ is the limit of the diagram
$$\cdots \to kQ/I^3 \to kQ/I^2 \to kQ/I.$$
In the linked question, the accepted answer confirms that the underlying $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of $\widehat{\mathbb{C} Q}$ is the product $P = \prod_{p \text{ path}} \mathbb{C} p$. However, I just don't see how this can be true.

Consider the canonical projection $\widehat{\mathbb{C} Q} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{C} Q/I^2$. Notice that $\mathbb{C} Q/I^2$ can be identified as the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space spanned by the paths of length strictly less than $2$. Let $q = (q_p)_p \in P$ be the tuple consisting precisely of the arrows (and having $0$-entries elsewhere), i.e. $q_p = p$ whenever $p \in A$ is an arrow, and $q_p = 0$ otherwise. Therefore, the image of $q$ in $kQ/I^2$ should be the sum of the arrows in $Q$. However, if $Q$ has infinitely many arrows, $q$ has infinitely many non-zero terms, so the sum is not defined.

Instead, if we construct the limit $\widehat{\mathbb{C} Q} = \varprojlim \mathbb{C} Q/I^n$ in the canonical way—as a closed subalgebra of the product $\prod_n \mathbb{C} Q/I^n$—shouldn't we find that
$$\widehat{\mathbb{C} Q} \cong \prod_{n \geq 0} \left( \bigoplus_{\operatorname{length}(p) = n} \mathbb{C} p \right)$$
consists of series, indexed by $n \geq 0$, of *finite* $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of paths of length $n$?

Comment: The question you link to is about finite quivers (i.e., with finitely many vertices and arrows).

Comment: Oh, I see my confusion, thank you for pointing this out. I remember reading a few months ago that one can complete the path algebra of an infinite quiver in some way to make it unital (so that it contains the sum of all the idempotents as an element). I was searching for that paper, stumbled across the linked answer and projected my interpretation onto it. Do you happen to know of the paper I'm referring to? If so, I would really appreciate it if you pointed me towards it. I'm starting to worry that I only dreamt of reading it...

Comment: Sorry, no, I don’t know the paper.